# PHP store 2 values into 1 array index

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to create a sort of multidimensional array which takes 2 values from a database and stores in into 1 index in the array

*Example x[0] = Jille, 595*

I'm doing this as such

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) 
{ 
    $opponents[] = $row['opponents']; 
    $fixId= array($row['fixture_id'] => $opponents) ; //Is this line correct??
}
```

Then later on in my code I want to use the $fixId array which should hold 2 values per index
I do this as such:

```
foreach($fixid as $id => $oppname){
    echo "<option value=\"$oppname\" >".$oppname;"</option>"; 
}
```

However it is not working the values `$id` and `$oppname` does not have a value or take on some strange value.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why don't you do `foreach ($opponents`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like that :

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) 
{ 
     $opponents[] = array('oppname' => $row['opponents'], 'oppid' => $row['fixture_id']) ; 
}


foreach ($opponents as $opp) {
     echo '<option value="'.$opp['oppid'].'">'.$opp['oppname'].'</option>';
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I tried it however the foreach loop has a syntax error. I looked it over but cant find the error, would you mind just giving it a scan. cheerz

Comment: Sorry one more question if you dont mind. How do I go about extracting  $opp['name'] in the $opposition array on a new page? At the moment the oppid gets passed when the form is submited..Is something like this correct? `foreach ($_REQUEST['opponents'] as $opponents){
   print $opponents;
   echo'<br>'; 
 }` It only gives me the id though and not the name...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$fixId = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) 
{ 
 $opponents[] = $row['opponents']; 
 $fixId[] = array('fixture_id' => $opponents) ;       
}
```

I made this test:

```
<?php
 $fixId = array();

 $opponents[] ="Jille, 595"; 
 $fixId[] = array('fixture_id' => $opponents) ;

 var_dump($fixId);
?>
```

Showing: `array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { ["fixture_id"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(10) "Jille, 595" } } }`